# Numpy arange over numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that basically returns [generalized harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers).

```
def harmonic(limit, z):
   return numpy.sum(1.0/numpy.arange(1, limit+1)**z)
```

Here is two examples for the current function definition:

```
>>> harmonic(1, 1)
1.0
>>> harmonic(2, 1)
1.5
```

As you might guess this works fine when `limit` is scalar, but how can I make this function work with 1D and 2D arrays as well?

The following demonstrates an example output of the function I want to achieve

```
>>> limit = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> harmonic(limit, 1)
array([[1.0, 1.5], [1.833, 2.083]])
```

Comment: Can you show some sort of an example?

Comment: @mert: what would you like the result to look like?  If x=arange(1,limit+1) and limit is 2D, I guess what you want is obvious for x[0,:] and x[:,0], but what about the other elements?

Comment: Do you want to compute the limit (when it exists) or are you interested on how it converges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only interested in vectorizing over `limit` and not `z`, as in the example you showed, then I think you can use [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
>>> h = np.vectorize(harmonic)
>>> h(1, 1)
array(1.0)
>>> h(2, 1)
array(1.5)
>>> h([[1,2], [3,4]], 1)
array([[ 1.        ,  1.5       ],
       [ 1.83333333,  2.08333333]])
>>> h([[1,2], [3,4]], 2)
array([[ 1.        ,  1.25      ],
       [ 1.36111111,  1.42361111]])
```

Note that this will return 0-dimensional arrays for the scalar case.

Actually, on second thought, it should work for the `z` case too:

```
>>> h([[2,2], [2,2]], [[1,2],[3,4]])
array([[ 1.5   ,  1.25  ],
       [ 1.125 ,  1.0625]])
```

Comment: In fact you also get vectorization over `z`, and broadcasting. See `h([1,2], [[1], [2]])` for example.

Comment: @jorgeca: yeah, I'm just incapable of doing arithmetic, so I didn't believe the output at first. :^)

Answer (score 0):

`arange` generates evenly spaced 1D ndarray in range `[1,limit+1]` in your example.

Now say you want an multi-dim ndarray of evenly spaced arrays. Then you may use [`arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) to generate each component of your 2D ndarray. You convert result of `arange` to a python list with `list()`, to make it the right format to be an argument of `ndarray` constructor.

It all depends on your purpose. As you deal with math. analysis, what you look for may be a grid:

```
>>> np.mgrid[0:5,0:5]
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]],
       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]])
```

[More here.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html)

EDIT:
After you posted the code : 
as DSM mentions, `np.vectorize` is a good way to do. [From doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html),

```
class numpy.vectorize(pyfunc, otypes='', doc=None, excluded=None, 
   cache=False)
```

> Generalized function class.
>
> Define a vectorized function which takes a nested sequence of objects
>   or numpy arrays as inputs and returns a numpy array as output. The
>   vectorized function evaluates pyfunc over successive tuples of the
>   input arrays like the python map function, except it uses the
>   broadcasting rules of numpy.

Comment: arange creates an ndarray instance, and it seems that you're making a distinction between arange and ndarray which doesn't make sense.